# If $(A - \lambda I_n)$ is singular, then there exist $X \in M_n(\mathbb{C}), X \neq 0 $ such that $AX= \lambda X $

Tags: linear-algebra

This question arise from *Hoffman & Kunze - Linear Algebra*, Sec. 8.5 Theorem 16. (page 313 on [this edition](https://docs.google.com/a/umich.edu/file/d/0B-87D9cxiLfibzN1UTRkWTdHVFk/edit?pref=2&pli=1)).

In the demonstratio it is given an argument about the existence of a root of the polynomial $det(A - \lambda I_n)$. So far so good. But then it says this implies the existence of a non-zero matrix $X$ such that $AX= \lambda X $.

I simply cannot understand how this follows. Am I missing something quite elemental here? Further clarifications are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say that we find a value $\lambda$ such that $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$. This implies that we can find a vector $\vec{x}$ such that
$$A\vec{x}=\lambda\vec{x}$$
Hence, if we construct a matrix with the columns as $\vec{x}$ then we have
$$\begin{align}
AX&=A\left[\vec{x}\;\;\vec{x}\;\; ...\;\;\vec{x}\right]\\
&=\left[\lambda\vec{x}\;\;\lambda\vec{x}\;\; ...\;\;\lambda\vec{x}\right] \\
&= \lambda\left[\vec{x}\;\;\vec{x}\;\; ...\;\;\vec{x}\right] \\
&= \lambda X
\end{align}$$
Here we did matrix multiplication one column at a time.
**EDIT**
Note that because $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$ we know that $A-\lambda I$ is singular. Hence there is a non - zero vector $\vec {x} $ such that
$$\begin {align}
(A-\lambda I)\vec {x}&= A\vec {x} -\lambda\vec {x} \\
&= 0
\end {align}$$
Thus we have
$$A\vec {x}=\lambda\vec {x}$$

Comment: Here I assume you have learned about eigenvalues. If not I can explain why $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$ implies we can find said vector $\vec{x}$.

Comment: Yes, this section of the book is posterior of eigenvalues section, but apparently I am missing something. I cannot see the connection between the first and second sentence of your reply.

Comment: Added an extra part.

Comment: Thank you so much. I get it now!